# Помогите расшифровать код javascript. Compose, reduce

Tags: javascript

Этот код фильтрует юзеров по возрасту, и возвращает массив имен, кто старше 18.
Но что конкретно делает строчка "**functions.reduceRight((arg, fn) => fn(arg), args)**"?

```
const compose = (...functions) => 
    args => functions.reduceRight((arg, fn) => fn(arg), args);

compose(map(u => u.name), filter(u => u.age >= 18))
```

Comment: http://prgssr.ru/development/kompoziciya-funkcij.html

Comment: `functions` это массив, а значит проходится по функциям справа-налево: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight

Comment: @entithat а вот это вот в конце - "fn(arg), args" - это что возвращается?

Comment: Что в конце? `args` это параметр `reduceRight`. `fn(arg)` меняет этот `args`. Поменяйте все стрелочные функции на обычные анонимные и не мучайтесь, сразу поймете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберемся

```
const compose = (...functions) => 
    args => functions.reduceRight((arg, fn) => fn(arg), args);

compose(map(u => u.name), filter(u => u.age >= 18));
```

1. `const compose = (...functions) ...`- объявление стрелочной функции с параметрами собранными в массив `functions`
2. `compose(map(u => u.name), filter(u => u.age >= 18))` - Вызов compose с параметрами: `functions[0] = map(u => u.name) и functions[1] = filter(u => u.age >= 18);`
3. `args => functions.reduceRight((arg, fn) => fn(arg), args);` - можно переписать так `(args) => { return functions.reduceRight((arg, fn) =>{ return fn(arg);}, args);}`
4. Вот мы и добрались до `functions.reduceRight((arg, fn) =>{ return fn(arg);}, args);` - эта строка вызывает `reduceRight` для массива `functions` в котором сидят наши функции с начальным значением `args` для аккумулятора `arg` и изменением его значения на каждой итерации на `fn(arg)` или если расписать то.

   ```
     arg = args; // начальное значение аккумулятора
     arg = functions[functions.lenght - 1](arg); // изменение значения аккумулятора на первой итерации
     arg = functions[functions.lenght - 2](arg);// второй итерации
     .....
     arg = functions[0](arg);// на последней итерации
     return arg;
   ```

Надеюсь что стало чуть яснее.

Comment: можете прочитать тут https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за такой исчерпывающий ответ! Сейчас все прояснилось)